# How to Upload image and text to remote server using cordova/phonegap on android

Tags: image, cordova, upload

Please I am working on a project that needs to get photo from phone camera and fill two text boxes and upload them to remote server using cordova/phonegap. I have tried this for weeks now without luck. I'm building on android platform. thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want from SO? Just for someone to send you code? You need to ask a focused question. See our [materials](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for asking questions on SO.

Comment: No! I need to know how to go about achieving the objective. Thanks

Comment: Meanwhile, can you be of help? Any positive help is welcome.

Comment: Please provide more information. With the information you've provided so far, there's nothing we can do.

Answer (score 3):

Create two functions you can call separately. One function for just getting the image, and another function to upload the image.
You can do something like below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Submit form</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    var pictureSource;   // picture source
    var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        pictureSource = navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
        destinationType = navigator.camera.DestinationType;
    }


    // Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
    //
    function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {

        // Show the selected image
        var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');
        smallImage.style.display = 'block';
        smallImage.src = imageURI;
    }


    // A button will call this function
    //
    function getPhoto(source) {
      // Retrieve image file location from specified source
      navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
        destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: source });
    }

    function uploadPhoto() {

        //selected photo URI is in the src attribute (we set this on getPhoto)
        var imageURI = document.getElementById('smallImage').getAttribute("src");
        if (!imageURI) {
            alert('Please select an image first.');
            return;
        }

        //set upload options
        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey = "file";
        options.fileName = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
// this will get value of text field
        options.params = {
            firstname: document.getElementById("firstname").value,
            lastname: document.getElementById("lastname").value,
            workplace: document.getElementById("workplace").value
        }

        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI("http://some.server.com/upload.php"), win, fail, options);
    }

    // Called if something bad happens.
    //
    function onFail(message) {
      console.log('Failed because: ' + message);
    }

    function win(r) {
        console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
        console.log("Response = " + r.response);
        //alert("Response =" + r.response);
        console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
    }

    function fail(error) {
        alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
        console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
        console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="regform">
        <button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);">Select Photo:</button><br>
        <img style="display:none;width:60px;height:60px;" id="smallImage" src="" />

        First Name: <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname"><br>
        Last Name: <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname"><br>
        Work Place: <input type="text" id="workplace" name="workPlace"><br>
        <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" onclick="uploadPhoto();">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

This code is working for me. Hope this helps.!

Answer (score 0):

There is a file transfer plugin (which you may or may not be trying to use; you gave NO details) for such things.  Or you can use straight javascript, ignoring cordova/phonegap completely.  The details will depend a fair bit on how the service expects to be interacted with.

Comment: pls I just edited my question to include the code I was working with.